# how to make loops from smallest to largest number?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, do-while

```
a = int(input("first number: "))
b = int(input("second number: "))
for x in range (a,b):
    print(x, end = ' ')
```

I am making a program that would display a number from smallest to largest.

For example: the first number is 10 then the second number is 1.

My expected result is: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

The program that I did is not working if a is lower than b, but is working if the a is higher than b.

Comment: I'm not following this.  Are you saying if ```a > b```, your script works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to always go from min to max regardless of which one is min and which is max you could do something like this:

```
for x in range(min(a, b), max(a, b)):
```

Comment: How would I make the smaller input number be the first number and the larger input number be the last number . like input 1: 10, input 2: 1  and it will result to 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Comment: Just add 1 to the end value if you want it to be inclusive, ie in this case range(min(a, b), max(a, b)+1).

Answer (score 1):

To count backwards, range has a `step` parameter: when set to -1, it will count backwards.

```
a = int(input("first number: "))
b = int(input("second number: "))

step = -1 if a > b else 1
for x in range (a, b, step):
    print(x, end = ' ')
```

Comment: I'm not yet familiar of these .but it sure works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count backwards then you can specify an additional stepsize of -1 as an argument to the range function as follows:

```
In [1]: list(range(1,10))
Out[1]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [2]: list(range(10,1))
Out[2]: []

In [3]: list(range(10,1,-1))
Out[3]: [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem as we need to print the number in ascending order not in descending order. @v.tralala